# Single update results in thousands of writes

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I'm looking for a viable answer to this use case.  There are music tracks, and users have playlists of tracks. Let's say a user uploads a track, then a week later decides to edit the name (or make the track private, etc).  If the track has been added to ~10k different playlists, that single edit results in ~10k writes.

It takes a single query to get all the playlists the track has been added to using
a reverse lookup table, then the application has to loop through all 10k
results and perform the respective updates on the playlist table.

The only alternative I see to this is performing a join at the application level when retrieving playlists.

This is a common use case I keep running into and would like to know how best to handle it.

```
CREATE TABLE tracks (
    track_id timeuuid,
    url text,
    name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (track_id)
)

CREATE TABLE playlist_ordered_by_recently_added (
    playlist_id timeuuid,
    date_added_id timeuuid,
    track_id timeuuid,
    url text,
    name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (playlist_id, date_added_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (date_added_id DESC)

CREATE TABLE playlist_ordered_by_recently_added_reverse_lookup (
    track_id,
    playlist_id,
    date_added_id,
    PRIMARY KEY (track_id, playlist_id)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The "join" approach is the correct one, though I wouldn't call it "join".
To retrieve the track list, you will need to issue a first query against playlist_ordedred_by_recently_added (which gives you all the track_id(s), which is expected to be reasonably small), followed by a bunch of parallel queries to retrieve the tracks.url and tracks.name from your tracks table.
When you update, you only need to update the tracks table to change the name, once.